# support on a triangle and uniform marginal distributions

Tags: probability, statistics, multivariable-calculus, probability-distributions

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are jointly distributed on the support $\operatorname{conv} \{(0,0),(0,1),(1,0)\}$ with the joint PDF $f>0$ everywhere on the support. Is it possible to find $f$ such that the marginal PDFs are given by

$f_X(x)= 1$ for all $x\in[0,1]$ and

$f_Y(y)=1$ for all $y\in [0,1]$?

Thanks

Comment: Certainly if $(X,Y)$ is uniformly distributed along the hypotenuse of that triangle, then $X$ and $Y$ separately are uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$.    But that joint distribution doesn't have a density with respect to the standard measure on the plane, since the area of the diagonal is $0$. $\qquad$

Comment: Hi, it is possible to find joint distribution with a density with respect to the standard measure and has a strictly positive density on the entire support (or some positive measure of the support)?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot have an everywhere positive density on the triangle support with the given marginal distributions.  To see this, suppse such a distribution exists, and then consider the small triangle to the right of $x=1/2$.  The x marginal distribution implies that the probability that x is greater than 1/2 is 1/2.  Similarly, the probability that y is greater than 1/2 is 1/2.  These 2 small triangles are disjoint, so the probability of being in one or the other is 1.  But that means that for the square where x and y are bounded by 0 and 1/2, the distribution will be zero almost everywhere.  So such a distribution does not exist.

Comment: I am afraid I don't understand: for me, the probability to be in one of these small triangles (e.g. conv$((1/2,0),(1,0),(1/2,1/2))$) is $1/2 \times 1/2 = 1/4$. Then for being in one or the other, its $1/4+1/4$. Could you say me where i'm wrong ?

Comment: @JeanMarie, you need to look at the marginal distribution for this.  You have a uniform joint distribution, not uniform  marginal distributions.

Comment: Pardon me, I don't want to bother you but when you say "You have a uniform joint distribution, not uniform marginal distributions" : it is the contrary that is said in the question...

Comment: @JeanMarie, correct.  I was describin your comment, which implies a uniform joint distribution .